# Placing Text and Image Next to Each Other in Div - CSS

Tags: html, css, wrapper, image

I'm trying to place a piece of text right next to an image inside a wrapper div, but all of my attempts have failed so far, and has resulted in me using an image to accomplish what I'm trying to do. I won't post my failed attempts in code as to avoid confusion, but what I've got so far:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/header.css" />

    </head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5" /></head>

<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="logo"><img src="/images/logo-top.png"></div>
    <div class="linked"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/me" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="/images/connect-linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn Profile" width="217" height="23" /></a></div>
</div>


<div id="header-bg"> 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    postion: fixed;
    width: 940px;
    height: 66px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 1;

} 



.logo {
    height: 66px;
    width: 171px;
    float: left;

}

.linked {
    height: 23px;
    width: 217px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-right: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: right;

}


#header-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;       
    background-image: url("/images/header-bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    z-index: -1;


}
```

**Which produces this:**
http://oi46.tinypic.com/2vmd9v8.jpg

^That's what I'm going for layout wise, but - I'd ultimately like to have "Connect with me on" and the LinkedIn logo separated into text and a logo image instead of one image clumped together.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to remove all those unnessicary divs. Make bg-header one div and change it to a class (assuming that bg-header is the black bar.) Within that div put the logo and the
 link image in there. Float the logo image left only and move both logo and link right by setting the desired amount of left padding for the bg-header class.

Like this

HTML

```
<div class="bg-header">
   <img src="/images/log-top.png>
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/me" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="/images/connect-linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn Profile" width="217" height="23" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bg-header { padding-left: /*Insert value here*/; }
img { float: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the padding with this css:

```
.logo {
height: 66px;
width: 171px;
float: left;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
}
.linked {
height: 23px;
width: 217px;
margin-top: 12px;
margin-right: 0;
left: 0;
float: right;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border: 0px;
}
```